# Create element inside of parent element in Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dojo

I can create a `div` inside the body like so:

```
var n = dojo.create("div", { innerHTML: "<p>helloWorld</p>" }, dojo.body());
```

I would like to create a `div` inside of my parent element such as this:

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var n = dojo.create("div", { innerHTML: "<p>helloWorld</p>" }, dojo.query('#parent'));
```

How can I create my `div` inside of my parent `div` which already exists in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you posted is entirely valid.  A couple of alternatives:

No need to look up the dom node, you  can pass in a String (the id of the node)

```
require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domConstruct){
  var n = domConstruct.create("div", { innerHTML: "<p>helloWorld</p>" }, 'parent');
});
```

Or you could construct the node and place it later using domConstruct#place:

```
require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domConstruct){
  var n = domConstruct.create("div", { innerHTML: "<p>helloWorld</p>" });
  domConstruct.place(n, 'parent');
});
```

domConstruct#place can also take an optional `position` parameter.  The [API Docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/dom-construct#place) have more information on it

Answer (score 1):

Should you need to target a class instead of a element id, I found the following to be and effective and easy to maintain method:

```
require([
  'dojo/query',
  'dojo/dom-construct'
  ], function(
    query,
    domConstruct,
  ){
  var parent = query('.someClass')[0];
  var child = domConstruct.create('div', { innerHTML: '<p>helloWorld</p>'});
  domConstruct.place(child, parent, 'position');
});
```

Given it is always better to target an id instead of a class, but in cases when you are relying on outside libraries that isn't always viable.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was this (I am open to any other solutions):

```
// dojo 1.7+ (AMD)
require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domConstruct){
  var n = domConstruct.create("div", { innerHTML: "<p>helloWorld</p>" }, dojo.byId('parent'));
});

// dojo < 1.7
var n = dojo.create("div", { innerHTML: "<p>helloWorld</p>" }, dojo.byId('parent'));
```